# IIS/WCF client certificate to user one-to-one mapping & internal server error

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, ssl

I've enabled client certificate authentication for my WCF service including map-client-certificate-to-windows-account:

```
<serviceCredentials>
  <clientCertificate>
    <authentication mapClientCertificateToWindowsAccount="True"/>
```

In the system.webServer configuration I've configured the following mappings:

```
<authentication>
  <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="true" oneToOneCertificateMappingsEnabled="true">
    <oneToOneMappings>
      <add enabled="true"
           userName="TestUser"
           password="CLEARTEXT_PASSWORD_FOR_DEVELOPER_TESTING"
           certificate="BASE64_ENCODED_CERTIFICATE"/>
```

However, when calling the service all I get is a `Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException` because the server is answering with 500.19 Internal Server Error - hinting that my configuration is invalid.

If I remove the mappings and reduce the client certificate validation to:

```
<serviceCredentials>
  <clientCertificate/>
```

the "normal" client certificate validation works just fine. So there is definitely something wrong with my certificate-mapping configuration. I've followed the tutorials - what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh boy, just found the problem: change:

```
<section name="iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

to `Allow` in your IIS' applicationHost.config!